# How to handle circular dependent data structure in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, data-structures, circular-dependency

I am setting up a new web application. There is a Laravel based API which interacts with an Angular Application. Now there is the following situation that will occur multiple times and i don't know how to handle it properly.

As an example there is a collection of users and projects. Both models are connected by an intermediate Table/Model ProjectTeam. I tried to illustrate the situation in the following picture:

[image: Model illustration]

Now if a user loggs in I want to load the user data with his projects. So my API will send me a JSON like:

```
[
  {
    id: 12,
    email: "example@mail.xy",
    projects: [
      {
        name: "Project X",
        created: 2019,
        ...
      },
      ...
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

But sometimes I want to load the project team (for example to admin the team) and I'll retrieve a JSON as follows: (Just the inverted version)

```
[
  {
    name: "Project X",
    created: 2019,
    team: [
      {
        id: 12,
        email: "example@mail.xy",
        ...
      },
      ...
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

Now in my angular application I instantiate an object for the retrieved data:

```
export class Project {
  name: string;
  created: number | Date;
  team: ProjectTeam;

  constructor(data: ProjectAPI) {
    this.name = data.name;
    this.created = data.created;
    this.team = new ProjectTeam(data.team);
  }
}

export interface ProjectAPI { ... }

export class ProjectTeam {
  members: []ProjectTeamMember;

  constructor(data) {
    this.members = data.map(elm => new ProjectTeamMember(elm));
  }
}

export class ProjectTeamMember {
  user: User;
  ...

  constructor(data) {
    this.user = new User(data);
  }
}

export class User {
  id: number;
  projects: []Project;
  ...

  constructor(data) {
    this.id = data.id;
    this.projects = data.projects ? data.projects.map(elm => new Project(elm)) : null;
    // Here i would get a circular dependency
    ...
  }
}
```

And i would do the same thing the other way around if i could, but then i would get a circular dependency.

So what's the proper way to handle this kind of problem? Or wouldn't you instantiate objects and just control nested data over an interface?

Thanks for your answers :)

Comment: you can identify the `users` based on the `team members` so you might not need the object `projects` in `Users` table

Comment: Its not the tables up there... That should show the models structures... I think i'll edit the post a bit to be more clear.

Comment: an interface is probably your best bet.